# Facebook Graph API, invalid/missing permissions trying to read leadgen data in webhook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm are having a problem trying to get data via Facebook's Graph API from a leadgen object, from a particular Facebook business.

A page admin user logs in and we request these permissions: manage_pages, pages_show_list, leads_retrieval, public_profile.

Then we set up a webhook to obtain leads from a leadgen form.

We also create a long lived token and store it in the server. Once we have all this setup, Facebook sends us any leadgen data via the configured webhook.

The data looks like this (sensitive data omited):

```
{
    "entry": [
    {
        "changes": [
        {
            "field": "leadgen",
            "value": {
                "created_time": ...,
                "page_id": "...",
                "form_id": "...",
                "leadgen_id": "..."
            }
        }
    ],
    "id": "...",
    "time": ...
    }
  ],
  "object": "page"
}
```

We retrieve the leads data via the /{leadgen_id} endpoint, and the long lived token.

We havent had any issues until today that we tried to connect to another business and recieved this:

```
CRM access has been revoked from Lead Access Manager.
```

After some research we noticed that we had to ask the user to enable our Facebook app in: Business Settings -> Integrations -> Leads Access -> CRM

It seems that our other users had the default settings set in the Manage Leads Access: By default, all Page admins and connected CRMs for {company name} can access leads.

But on the company that had activated the Lead Access Manager, when we query the /{leadgen_id} endpoint we recieve this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '...' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 33,
    "fbtrace_id": "..."
  }
}
```

We tried accessing https://developers.facebook.com/tools/visibility, but It does not give us any insight on the error.

Besides that we are also getting an error whe we access https://developers.facebook.com/support/

```
App health status
Your app received privacy errors during a recent Graph API request. As a result, your app may not function properly until the issue is resolved.
```

I'm guessing that we have to ask for some other permission or something, but its not clear what or which permission we should ask for in this case.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone wondering how to solve this same situation at the end of 2020, here's what I did to solved the problem (this assume you have Business Admin Role for your Page)

1. Create A System User In Business Settings Page, Add Asset and select your Page to it
2. Go to Integration -> Leads Access, Select your page, and Assign People then select your newly created System Users to it
3. Back to System User menu and generate your System Users token, you will need at least `ads_management, pages_read_engagement, pages_show_list, pages_manage_metadata, leads_retrieval, pages_manage_ads` permission to read the leads detail
4. Copy your generated token, and use it as access token for accessing facebook graph api with your leadgen_id

The steps above assume you only need to retrieve the leads detail. if you are planning on using the page access token, *then your user must be added to the Leads Access*, and then you can continue to create your apps page access token using your own access token

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so its seems the issue was because one of the users created the token, and then it was updated by another user, for some reason this caused the error. Both users are admins from the same page.

I still need to debug the exact cause of this, but the issue was that we where sending another token to the Graph API.

Comment: im getting the same error, i generated the token and it seems to be fine, the app is subscribed and everything, but i keep getting the same error when i send the test data from the form :/ error code 103 CRM access has been revoked from Lead Access Manager. and im not using CRM im sending the data to a webhook

Comment: That webhook you are sending the data to is treated as a CRM (at least thats what its called in Facebook), so check the user's and the page's access in Business Manager